# jQuery Progress Bar for File Upload

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I am facing a very weird issue.

Thing is, I made a file upload form with progress bar indication to work. I used this script:
[Malsup jQuery Form](http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js)

It worked fine. In my localhost, the progress indication was in light green color (Chrome & Firefox), and then I uploaded these files to my server. Now here comes the problem.

Usually, I never use such direct source for linking the scripts, I copy the script, put it in my js directory and work so that even in future if the uploader deletes it, my site functionality won't stop. So, I took a saved that js file and uploaded here: 
[A copy of the JS file in my site](http://ankursinha.net/TestSite/bootstrap/js/jqupload.js). But the script stops working, no progress is shown while uploading. (I have a strange feeling may be there are some API or some other things in that JS file connected to the uploader's github account or something). I want to know why this happens and what to do when such things happen.

Another problem is, after uploading it to my server, the progress bar color changed to blue by itself (may be because of bootstrap, my strange feeling), but when I used inline styling and put the color as black, it still came blue.

So what I want is, how to get the script work with the one which is there on my server and how to change the upload progress bar color from blue to black.

Here is the link to my site: [File Upload With Progress Bar](http://ankursinha.net/TestSite/fileshare/upload_file.php) (Please do not upload files larger than 3 MB, images, zip, rar, and office files alone supported)

Thank You

Comment: Refer this link: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404705/jquery-file-upload-plugin-progress-bar][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404705/jquery-file-upload-plugin-progress-bar

Comment: Everything works for me but in an unusual way, and I want to know the reason behind it. You have given me some link which was not of much use to me, sorry if that was rude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this script posted by [9Lessons](http://www.9lessons.info/2012/04/file-upload-progress-bar-with-jquery.html), it a very simple tutorial + implementation so you can configure it to your choices without depending on a 3rd party script.

Comment: Yeah, I have seen that. Unfortunately my hosting doesn't allow APC installation on their server.

Comment: Thats bad. I mean, even on most shared hosting they install APC if raise a ticket. Or atleash they will give access to run the commands through putty.

Comment: I know, my hosting providers bluntly said "We can't do. Installing APC might affect other users!"